# Ionic + Reactjs, Can't handle onChange TextField Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

i can't fill this field with more than 1 character. if i try to fill and always stop after 1 character

**form.js**

```
const [ referral,setReferral] = useState('');
...
<CssTextField
    className={classes.textField}
    label="Referral"
    variant="outlined"
    name="referral"
    id="custom-css-outlined-input"
    InputProps={{
        style: {
            border : borderColorReferral,
            borderRadius : "0px 10px 10px 0px"
        },
        onChange : (e) => {setReferral(e.target.value)},
        value : referral
    }}
    InputLabelProps={{
        style : {
            color:colorReferral,
            padding:"0px 6px"
        }
    }}
/>
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9duIg.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4XM6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ionic uses `onIonChange` instead of `onChange` directly, so you will want to make sure you map those events correctly